# How can I make a JTable refresh automatically from a text file?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jbutton

My code to refresh data is below but after pressing a button
I need to run the code every time I make changes to the text file.

Here is my code:

```
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    // Refresh Button
    try {
        for (int r = 0; r < 100; r++) { //initializing row
            for (int c = 0; c < 4; c++) { //initializing column
                jTable1.setValueAt(null, r, c);
            }
        }

        BufferedReader rdfile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("items.txt"));

        String[] item = new String[100];
        String[] temp;

        int x = 0;  //read item
        while ((item[x] = rdfile.readLine()) != null) {
            temp = item[x].split("\t");
            jTable1.setValueAt((1000 + x + 1), x, 0);
            for (int j = 1; j < 4; j++) {
                jTable1.setValueAt(temp[j - 1], x, j);
            }

            x++;
        }
        rdfile.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
}
```

Comment: `i need to run the code every time i make changes to the text file` - why are you changing the text file? Why don't you update the table at the same time you update the text file?

Comment: Java != Javascript

Comment: You could do it using a swing timer and lastModified () method of file class. But you should clarify what you are trying to achieve ...

Comment: [Watching a Directory for Changes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html)

Comment: `} catch (IOException e) { }` Don't ignore exceptions! They inform us exactly what went wrong. Unless logging is implemented, at least call `Throwable.printStackTrace()`

Comment: there is another part of the software that needs me to ignore exceptions or it will be too slow

Comment: sill no solution, i'm trying to refresh my jtable as soon as i open my application